# ANOVA or T-test for multiple groups, each group with a set of observations?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, experiment-design, research-design

Can someone please advise on which sort of experiment or test I should run for the following.

I want to know which messages would potentially resonate more within a population. I have conducted research (focus groups, and surveys) and have 5 main themes of messages. I want to test which of these themes I should use when communicating on social media.

The best way I can think of to test each theme is to create 5 adverts/social posts for each theme.

**For example:**

Theme 1 - pride:
post1, post2, post3, post4, post5

Theme 2 - heritage:
post1, post2, post3, post4, post5

Theme 3 - legacy:
post1, post2, post3, post4, post5

Theme 4 - love:
post1, post2, post3, post4, post5

Theme 5 - generosity:
post1, post2, post3, post4, post5

What kind of test do you recommend?

Some researchers recommend an ANOVA, or Kruskall-wallis, but my sample sizes could never be enough for these tests.

Some colleagues recommend a t-test, but I worry that the combined p values would be too high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally a one-way ANOVA test problem. If what you care most about is pairwise comparisons between groups, you could use p-value adjustments such as a Bonferroni adjustment.

The Kruskal-wallis test is non-parametric, and by definition has no sample size requirement. However, you may have been advised to use another test because your advisors believe you will not have enough power to detect the effect size. This, however, is not really solvable by choosing a different test. It simply requires you collect more data.

In summary, a Kruskall-wallis should be fine, but you need to be aware of the power relationships related to your sample size. It's unclear from your post if each post is an observations, or if each *interaction* with a post is a observations. This could substantially change your sample size.

Comment: Thank you for this, the Kruskall-Wallis test was the one I was leaning towards for what I wanted to know.

Regarding if each post vs each interaction is an observation, I assumed that it would be each post as an observation and not each interaction. How would each interaction work? 

If I had for example, post1 which received 10 interactions. This would be a value of 10 at the post level, but if I used interactions level I would have post1 with 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1? And, since I have 5 posts per group, I would just have a set of 1s for each post? Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: If that's you're study design, then yes, that is most likely each post. I thought if perhaps you were measuring positive vs. negative interactions you could change your unit of analysis.